# Backbone script executing before document fully loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am building my first rails app with backbone and because of the asset pipeline the Javascript is getting called/executed even before the document fully loads. So, none of the event handlers are getting attached. If I place this Javascript after the HTML tags at the end of the document, then it seems to work fine. How can I have this code execute after the page is fully loaded? I can always use jQuery's document.ready(), but I was hoping backbone has an inbuilt process to deal with it.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      "use strict";
      var app;

      app = {};

      app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "body",
        initialize: function() {
          this.playAudio();
        },
        events: {
          "click .play-audio": "playAudio"
        },
        playAudio: function() {
          alert($("span").data("audio"));
        }
      });

      app.appView = new app.AppView();

    }).call(this);

</script>

<div>
    <p>Whatever!</p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up play-audio" data-audio="http://my-audio-file"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Backbone is built on top of jQuery.. And the HTML page is parsed top down. So if you are not using a Asyn library like `require.js` you will always see the issue that you are experiencing if you are not declaring your code inside `DOM.ready` handler.. And it is always a best approach to declare `JS` code after HTML to avoid running the script before the page starts rendering..

Comment: Thanks, I will consider using require.js. For now, I might just move the JS script tag to the bottom of the page - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038484/putting-javascript-at-the-end-of-the-file-using-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign your function as document.onload or window.onload property. Both does almost the same thing but mostly depends on browser.

```
 <script> document.onload=(...your function goes here....) </script>
 //OR
 <script> window.onload=(...your function goes here....) </script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Moving all my javascript to the end of the page resolved this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038484/putting-javascript-at-the-end-of-the-file-using-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to execute your code is by using the DOMContentLoaded event listener:

Here's how:

```
 <script>
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   //your code here
  });
 </script>
```

Other useful event listeners are:

```
 window.onload = myfunction() ;
 //or
 document.onload = myfunction();
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily overwrite the default render method for this.
Simply like this: (excuse me my coffee-script)

```
render: () ->
  super()
  @customMethodToRunAfterThePageIsLoaded()
```

I use it for after-page-load calculations which are inserted into the html with jQuery.